# android + access remote drawables - best practices

Tags: android, drawable

Im developing an app which is a product catalogue. Users can search for and view products (books). It's all read only and just so allow user's to view products. When the user clicks on a product, the next screen displays
- book title
- book author
- picture of front cover.

It's the picture part that I've a question about. I know one way to present drawables is to have them in the "drawable" direction in my android project and access them (in my xml file) as android:src="@drawable/name".

Only problem is that new products will be added so I can't store drawables in the APK file when I release it. I'll need to read them at runtime. I'm wondering what the best way to approach this is.

I'm thinking of upon (very first) launch of the app executing an AsyncTask which would call
openConnection of HttpURLConnection and would grab down all drawable (from a particular remote directory on a website) and would then store them in the sqllite db (as a blob). Each product in the db could easily be associated with it's specific drawable.

Not sure if there's a better approach to this ? or should I save them to the internal storage of the device (I know the size is an issue with this option). Trying to grab the drawable on demand can take 2-4secs (i.e. to get from remote server). Is there a way to download drawables in an efficent way ?

Update: The only problem with the above approach is the time it takes to grab the remote drawable and render it on the device (between 2-7 seconds). So I can't go with that approach for performance reasons. When the user launches the app for the very first time, it (using an ASynch task) grabs all products (in a csv remotely) and stores it's contents in an SQLLite db. So they've a small acceptable wait on very first launch of the app but none after that. I'd like to do something similiar (i.e. get the drawables too) but not sure should should I store them in internal storage or persist them as BLOB into the db. There max size of 2-3kb each in size but there could be 300 products in total

Any help would be great. I'm developing on Android 4.0.3.

Thanks - Ro

Answer (score 2):

The method you described is the best way to perform such a task. Grab them directly from online so that any time you change the picture it is changed on your phone. Also an easier way, you can directly display images to user no need for storing them into database but before you have to check internet connection.

Function for retrieving images:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFile(String str)
    {
        Bitmap bmImg=null;
        URL myFileUrl;
        try {
            myFileUrl = new URL(str);
            HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)myFileUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bmImg;

    }
```

For checking Internet connection:

```
// declaring variable for holding Internet connection state
        boolean connected = false;
        // checking connectivity to the Internet through mobile network or WIFI
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if(connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || 
                    connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                // Internet connection
                connected = true;
            }
            else
                // no Internet connection
                connected = false;
```

Example:

```
            // grab image to display
            try {
                // Bitmap bmp1;
                    // String url1;
                    // ImageView img1;

                // in case there is Internet connection display image from online url
                if(connected == true)
                {
                    bmp1=MainActivity.getBitmapFile(url1); 
                    img1.setImageBitmap(bmp1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.not_connected);
                    }
                } catch(Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }
```

Comment: Hi Lucien, Thanks for the response. I've updated the original post with a comment (see 'UPDATE') as I can't seem to 'reply' to your answer